# Install Xcode app Without certificate

Tags: ios, xcode, jailbreak

I want to install my term project app on my iPhone, the class gave me a developer account but the professor never "got around" to helping me provision it for debugging.

I'm jailbroken too so I figure there must be a way to get it on there, can anyone help?

Comment: Can you login to this account and successfully get to the developer portal/ITC?

Comment: Yea I can get in.  The professor made it seem like there was something we'd need from her to get it to work, it's a University license that we're using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are ways for jailbroken iPhone.
This one works well for iOS 5, but without debugging:
http://techtalktone.wordpress.com/2011/12/05/testing-your-ios-apps-on-a-jailbroken-device-2/

EDIT:
After upgrading to the latest xcode from appstore, (I think is 4.3.2) and iOS sdk 5.1, there seems to be a problem with the final part of the guide (where you tell Xcode to allow it)

It didn't work for me as well.
the problem is that since the new Xcode, the Developer folder no longer exists.
I managed to find the new command so it now works for me:
instead of

```
sudo /usr/bin/sed -i .bak ‘s/XCiPhoneOSCodeSignContext/XCCodeSignContext/’ /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Info.plist
```

it should now be:

```
sudo /usr/bin/sed -i .bak ‘s/XCiPhoneOSCodeSignContext/XCCodeSignContext/’ /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Info.plist
```

I hope I didn't misspelled anything as i'm writing it from windows and can't verify. just use TAB for the auto completion of the command

After you do this, you need to go into your project, to the build settings and change all the code sign fields (5, i think) to the name of your newly created certificate.

Hope this helps now. If it doesn't let me know.

Comment: I'm going to try this out now, hopefully it will work I'm not worried at all about debugging I just want to use it!

Comment: I was having some trouble with that....gonna have to wait until the semester is over, almost borked my development environment

Comment: After you do this, you need to go into your project, to the build settings and change all the code sign fields (5, i think) to the name of your newly created certificate.

Comment: I was getting errors when running one of the commands.  I've used Linux primarily for years but it wasn't anything I was familiar with.  I panicked when I realized my projects wouldn't build anymore, I had to give a presentation of my app so this was pretty bad.  I uninstalled and reinstalled and everything was fine.  Semester is over now so I'm gonna take another whack at it.  Pretty annoyed I'm having so much trouble getting my own app on my own phone but it still beats the chaos of the Android world.

Comment: I'm running the absolute latest version of Xcode from the App Store, which I think must be different because I'm getting lots of file not found errors in the last part of the tutorial labeled 

4. Conclude the requirement removal through patching Xcode. This means binary editing:

I'm an OSX newb so this might be simple, but I don't understand the spaces and the backslashes like in the dd command and even the cd command now that I'm looking at it.....still messing around, finals are over got nothing to lose.  Thanks for the nudge in the right direction at least I know it's possible!

Comment: edited my answer, it should work now. I had problems too once I upgraded to the latest xcode

Comment: Yep that was it, thanks a bunch it worked, I don't understand what the\ backslashes\ and\ spaces\ in that first command meant, but running the one that you added in your edited post did it.  Thanks a lot, now I can start deciding what to put on my own phone like a big kid!