# iOS - install application from XCode without Developer Program subscription removed SDKs

Tags: ios, xcode

I have tried to deploy an iOS application to an actual device (iPad 2, OS version 7.0.4). I followed [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37522/1374416) with regards to creating my own self-signed certificate. However, the final step that sets the iPhone SDK to use the certificate was not updated so I used [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10357610/1374416) and replaced it with `sudo /usr/bin/sed -i .bak 's/XCiPhoneOSCodeSignContext/XCCodeSignContext/' /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Info.plist` instead.

I had to restart XCode (Version 4.6.3), changed the code sign fields. However, when I tried to deploy the application, it seemed that the SDKs for iPad and iPhone were not there any more. So I tried to create a new application, and when the dialog box appeared for the project template, the iPad and iPhone options were gone. [image: As seen in this image]

Do I have to reinstall the SDKs? My worry here is that if I do, the certificate I created might be invalidated, and if I repeat the process, I might screw up the SDKs again.

Any help is very much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Note that `/XCiPhoneOSCodeSignContext/XCCodeSignContext/' /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Info.plist` is a *binary property list* file. Modifying that with "sed" probably damaged it.

Comment: Sorry but I'm new when it comes to iOS Development. Any way I could bring it back?